Python subprocess.popen deadlocking if manipulating stdin and stdout?
I wrote a script to manipulate stdin and stdout for a chess engine. Basically I open the program with subprocess.popen and manipulate input and output using threading.Thread for each.
However, if several instances of my script are spawned, the program stops working after like 15 minutes. I presume that is the deadlock due to a full buffer described by the documentation. Unfortunately, I cannot use the recommended "communicate" function, because I need to modify both input and output continuously. Is there any way how to deal with that? Here's a minimal version of what I do:
import sys
import time
import subprocess
import threading


class ChessEngine:

    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def write(self, command):
        with self.lock:
            self.engine.stdin.write(command + "\n")
            self.engine.stdin.flush()

    def read_stdout(self):
        while True:
            text = self.engine.stdout.readline()
            text = text.replace("foo", "bar")
            print(text, end="", flush=True)

    def read_stdin(self):
        while True:
            command = input()
            command = command.replace("foo", "bar")
            self.write(command)

    def run(self):
        self.engine = subprocess.Popen(
            "/usr/games/stockfish",
            shell=True,
            universal_newlines=True,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
            bufsize=1,
            cwd=self.folder,
        )
        threading.Thread(target=self.read_stdout, daemon=True).start()
        threading.Thread(target=self.read_stdin, daemon=True).start()
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            if not self.engine.poll() is None:
                sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    chess_engine = ChessEngine()
    chess_engine.run()


I looked for several ways how to make sure the script is not blocking - without success.

Seems like the real problem stderr buffer filling up because you doesn't read it.  So, if you doesn't read stderr, you can discard it:
self.engine = subprocess.Popen(
    "/usr/games/stockfish",
    shell=True,
    universal_newlines=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,  # DISCARD IT!
    bufsize=1,
    cwd=self.folder,
)

In this case, buffer wouldn't filled up.
Also you could redirect stderr to stdout, as you reading it in read_stdin:
self.engine = subprocess.Popen(
    "/usr/games/stockfish",
    shell=True,
    universal_newlines=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,  # REDIRECT IT
    bufsize=1,
    cwd=self.folder,
)

This solution could work as well.
And finally you could start reading your stderr in another Thread:
def read_stderr(self):
    while True:
        text = self.engine.stderr.readline()
        ...
        pass

def run(self):
    self.engine = subprocess.Popen(
        "/usr/games/stockfish",
        shell=True,
        universal_newlines=True,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        bufsize=1,
        cwd=self.folder,
    )
    threading.Thread(target=self.read_stdout, daemon=True).start()
    threading.Thread(target=self.read_stdin, daemon=True).start()
    threading.Thread(target=self.read_stderr, daemon=True).start()  # START REEAD THIS
    ...


Well spotted, but unfortunately this does not fix it, as there is just no stderr output... I edited my post.
